# data forward to search page instead of form action page

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a newsletter form which forward the data to newsletter.php but search.php page open when click on submit my form html code is:

```
<form action="../newsletter.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="field"   placeholder="Your Name" name="name" />
<input type="text" class="field"  placeholder="Email" name="email" />
<div class="form-buttons"><input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="submit-btn" />
</div>  </form>
```

Comment: Try use full URL path instead of relative, so for example `../newsletter.php` becomes `/your/page/newsletter.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your entire file don't have another  declaration. Maybe you have another form opened, and this newsletter form is inside of the other one. This will always submit the parent form.

Look for a

Comment: thanks another my form not closed which redirects it search.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a redirect to search.php on your newsletter.php page.